# SimpleScreenRecorder ERROR - missing codecs?

Tags: 14.04

I just used simplescreenrecorder to make a lengthy recording. I tested all of my settings in a test recording, and everything worked wonderfully in the playback. Unfortunately my latest recording will not play. I receive the following error message:

> An audio or video stream is not handled due to missing codecs. You
>   might need to install additional plugins to be able to play some types
>   of movies

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following in a new terminal window :

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
`sudo apt-get install update`

Additionally, you can install VLC media player for streaming :

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: Unfortunately VLC player does not load the video file either.